# Remote acces to Sharepoint 2010

Tags: windows-7, sharepoint-2010, windows-server-2008

I'm very new to sharepoint 2010.
Since I have Win 7 32 bits in my machine, I can't install SP2010.so, I want to install it on another machine that is using windows server 2008 as system operator.then I want to acces sharepoint from my machine(Win7 x86) using internet or shared domain.
Is it possible and how ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is possible.

Access to SharePoint sites and even Central Administration is all web-browser based so you just need to ensure you can connect to your server from your Windows 7 machine over HTTP.

Comment: Thanks for answering! I want to use sharepoint as a reporting platform.it is still possible to access the the business intelligence center ?

Comment: Yes, all end user access should be web-browser based. There may be some initial setup tasks that require you to be logged onto the server but day to day usage would be through the browser.